# Did Dedekind show any evidence of pictorial geometric sense?

Tags: mathematics, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

The most pictorial geometric thinking I find in Dedekind is the intuitive-geometric idea of a continuum which he criticizes as too vague before he gives his account of the continuum based on cuts.

In sharp contrast to Riemann, who Dedekind whole-heartedly praises, Dedekind and Weber prove the Riemann-Roch theorem without so much as using the word "Curve (Kurve);" and using the word "surface (Fläche)" only in describing Riemann's own work.

Dedekind was a great geometrizer in the sense of formalizing ideas of dimension and genus and differentials.  But so far as I have found he really does not see these pictorially.

It is not just that he does not trust pictorial thinking in proofs.  Lots of people who do not trust pictures *in* proofs still give pictures *with* their proofs.

Is there some pictorial thinking in Dedekind that I have missed?

ADDED: 
K.B.'s answer points to a peculiarly non-visual visualization, where Dedekind says he *cannot* see the elements of a set.  The best source I can find is a editorial note by Emmy Noether in Dedekind's *Gesammelte mathematische Werke* vol. 3 p. 449.

> Dedekind expressed himself on the concept of a set saying:  one
>   represents a set as a closed sack, containing completely determinate
>   things, but one cannot see them, and one knows only that they are
>   determinate and are there.

The German is a bit more subtle:

> Dedekind äußerte hinsichtlich des Begriffs der Menge: er stelle sich
>   eine Menge vor wie einen geschlossenen Sack, der ganz bestimmte Dinge
>   enthalte, die man aber nicht sehe, und von denen man nichts wisse,
>   außer daß sie bestimmt und vorhanden seien.

Comment: I think to redefine the real axis you really had to have a problem with geometry in your childhood ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to Bernstein, Dedekind imagined a set like a closed sack containing certain defined things. [Becker: Grundlagen, S. 316] Isn't that an example of pictorial thinking?

Comment: This would seem to be pictorial but not pictorial-geometric thinking, and the latter is what the question is about.